# What is wrong with merge commits?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I see a lot of questions where people are asking how that can avoid "pointless" merge commits.

What exactly is bad about a merge commit? I find them useful, as you can see exactly where two developers started working, and where there work is merged together. It seems like rebasing, as a lot of answers suggest doing, destroys this information and you lose a lot of the project's history.

Is there something I am missing that makes a merge commit undesirable?

Comment: I was actually wondering if there are cases when merge commits are actually *really*, **really** useful.  (The case you mention does not sound too convincing, frankly...)  I wonder if anyone would want to elaborate on that...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are two different kind of merge commits:

- Explicit merge commits, which result for example from explicitly merging a feature branch into the main branch
- and implicit merge commits, which result for example by doing a `git pull` before trying to push

The explicit merge commits are usually perfectly fine. You usually even enforce those kind of merge commits by saying `git merge --no-ff`.

The implicit ones tent to be just noise, as the typical situation is, that one developer changed one file and afterwards another developer works on another file but forgot to pull before doing the changes, and a `git pull` will implicitly merge both commits by creating a noisy merge commit. The more logical history would be simply one commit from the one author and one commit from the other author. Doing `git pull --rebase` will exactly do that.

Of course there are exceptions. If both authors actually worked on the same file, it might be better to have a merge commit at this point. - But even in this case maybe a rebase might be better, as it makes the changes against the first commit more explicit and therefore less error-prone.

Comment: But if you have a implicit merge, but you solve it wouldn't it be actually good to have that in your history? Then you can see what Git did for you automatically. I mean even without conflicts its relevant. Because a commit was based on a certain state, which might not be valid after a pull/fetch/rebase/merge.

Comment: @WouterSchut It does preserve the information about what exact state the codebase was in, but in practice I'd say it's not worth the noise.  Normally if you study history you are more interested in who, and why, and commit messages already provide far better way to pass this.  Also if the state is so significantly different, and someone did not consciously, honestly and carefully address those differences (eg. consider if given the new state, their feature is still worth) when merging/rebasing, they you probably have a bigger problem anyway.

Comment: I love this name: "Implicit Merge Commits"! But the example was too vague for me, can you explain a bit more? That's fine though, it makes complete sense to me even without that example, if there are any conflicts when doing git pull, then (unless it fails due to --ff-only) it will require resolving the merge conflicts which will then be an extraneous commit. But I'm still curious if a merge commit can be generated even WITHOUT any conflicts? As it sounds so in your example? The answer is great anyway, thank you.