# Good practice to delete after merge? If deleted, how do I track merging history?

Tags: git, github, smartgit

My buddy and I are working on a personal project, making branches as we go, and merging them back into master when the feature is done. But merging, and then deleting the branch, makes it a straight line on the log (see picture), which seems bad for keeping track of history. What should we do to work as a team and track history like it shows before a branch is deleted?

[image: Log in SmartGit before branch is deleted]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you merge a feature branch to master and no other commits were made on master, git defaults to a fast-forward-merge. This means it will not do a real merge but simply forward master to the current commit. This results in the correct content, but causes this usually unwanted linear history.

You usually do `git merge --no-ff` to avoid fast-forward merges and create an explicit merge commit.

Also have a look at [What is wrong with merge commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20211016/1870481).

Comment: I changed the correct answer to this, because looking back, this is what happened to me. Thank you for the helpful and non-rude answer.